# How to do a custom 2D Kernel on Filter2D using 1D gaussian kernel

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, kernel, filtering

I'm trying to replicate sequence of filters on my image, for this I need to create kernel, that contains the Filter2D kernel and Gaussian kernel. normally we apply a gaussianBlur and then a filter2D. The common commands for this is:

```
kernel2D= Mat::ones(kernelSize, kernelSize, CV_32F) *(1 / (float)(kernelSize*kernelSize)), Point(-1, -1);
GaussianBlur(src, resultO, Size(kernelSize, kernelSize), sigma);
filter2D(resultO, resultO, resultO.depth(), kernel2D, Point(-1, -1),0,BORDER_DEFAULT);
```

So, first I create a gaussian kernel, using getGaussianKernel method, and 1D kernel using Mat::Ones. I trying to multiplicate this two kernels to get the same result, as the code above.

```
    sigma = 0;
    Mat mKernelGauss1 = getGaussianKernel(kernelSize, sigma, CV_32F);
    mKernel2D = Mat::ones(1, kernelSize, CV_32F) *(1 / (float)(1*kernelSize)), Point(-1, -1);
    mResultKernel = mKernelGauss1 * mKernel2D;
```

When I do this process, I get a kernelSize x kernelSize Kernel as result , So then I can apply this kernel(mResultKernel) in my image, like this:

```
filter2D(src, resultO, src.depth(), mResultKernel, Point(-1, -1), 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
```

My problem is this kernel which I create don't give to me the same result as doing the gaussianBlur and filter2D sequentially. I really need follow this method, to convolution my image and apply the filter2D function using only one 2D kernel, like I showed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have confused betweeen multiplication and convolution. You can use a filter `h(x)` alter for two sequence filter `f(x)` and `g(x)` by this fomular:
`h(x) = f(x) * g(x)` which * is convolution operator. For matrix convolution you can refer [this lecture](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/cfcs1/lectures/cfcs_l15.pdf).

Comment: Thank you to the references, but I'm already convolving the image using filter2D, I only need to generate the kernel. And that's is my problem.